# how can i play rtsp video stream in flutter windows?

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, rtsp, ip-camera

I did not find packages for working with RTSP on windows on pub.dev, tell me how can I solve this problem and play the RTSP stream on windows flutter program? I had thoughts of using the VLC API, but I don't know yet if this is the right solution.

I tried to enable RTSP through existing packages. But there the picture is not updated and everything freezes on one frame.

Comment: I think VLC is the right choice which uses ffmpeg and supports plenty of other protocols like RTMP, RTSP, SRT, HLS. Is there any issue with the VLC package?

Comment: @sudayn but the problem is that all packages for working with RTSP work only on android and ios. I have not found a solution for windows